# React Native: Fetching from API gives: Unexpected End Of JSON File

Tags: react-native, expo, fetch-api

I am using React Native Expo and I am trying to fetch data from Fantasy API but when I parse the fetched data to JSON it says:

> **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**.

This is the code I use for fetching:

```
fetch("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
     return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("DATA: ", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
```

Please add into consideration that the data is fetched properly when I use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).
The provided code works for other APIs. I do not know why it does not work with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Get request don't need headers so remove it and it will work.